# Use javascript bookmark for specific iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a javascript debug code that I need to run from time to time on specific website.

The site has several iframes.

When I use Chrome's debug console I can choose which iFrame to run the code.

I created a bookmark with the code `javascript:my_debug_code()` - but how can I tell it to run on the iFrame I need?

**Edit**

This is not a duplicate of [Invoking JavaScript code in an iframe from the parent page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/invoking-javascript-code-in-an-iframe-from-the-parent-page) as was suggested.

Since I wasn't trying to run the code from the page itself.

My question is different - I want to run the code from a bookmark.

**Answer**

I can't post a new answer, because question is marked is duplicated.

But taken from @Gothdo answer, apparently all it took for me was to add to my bookmark:

```
javascript:window.frames[0].my_debug_code()
```

Comment: Use `frameName.contentWindow.my_debug_code()`. In simple words, it is **not possible** because of security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this provided that the iframe has the same origin as the main window. Simply create a new script and append it to the `<head>` element of that iframe.

```
const code = "console.log('hello world from iframe', location.href)"
     ,iframeName = "YOUR-IFRAME-NAME"

const script = document.createElement("script")
window.frames[iframeName].document.head.appendChild(script)
script.src = "data:text/javascript;base64," + btoa(code)
```

Comment: I have found the correct answer from this answer. I didn't need the entire script. Just the windows.frames[num] which did the trick for me.